# Net core 3.1 exception while hosting api as window service

Tags: api, .net-core

Getting exception Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException when using UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()) code with  UseWindowsService(), its saying that
An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostOptions], Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeOptions])' on type 'WindowsServiceLifetime'.

In dependency some of the dependecny are of request lifetime also

Comment: Resolved using v6.0.0 of the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices. <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />